# Se puede usar el femenino singular de un adjetivo como adverbio

Tags: gramática

Se podría por ejemplo utilizar "rápida" en una oración, pero con la función de adverbio. Es que he visto a gente con conocimiento en esto usar el femenino singular de un adjetivo como adverbio

Comment: La cuestión que habías planteado debería ir aquí, en "Add a comment", por ese motivo ha sido eliminada por Glorfindel.  Sobre tu pregunta, si los adjetivos invariables se pueden o podrían usar sin el sufijo o terminación (mente) como adverbio, en la respuesta que te di se halla también la contestación en gris más claro y una referencia, por si te resulta mejor visualizarla, donde te aclaran todas esas dudas. Referencia

http://hispanoteca.eu/gram%C3%A1ticas/Gram%C3%A1tica%20espa%C3%B1ola/Adverbios%20adjetivales%20o%20cortos.htm  Gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aunque un adjetivo puede convertirse en un adverbio si añadimos la terminación -mente. Por ejemplo: **tranquila** (adjetivo) – **tranquilamente** (adverbio), feliz (adjetivo) – felizmente (adverbio). **Rápido** es un adjetivo que funciona como adverbio cuando equivale a **rápidamente**. Ejem. "Caminemos **rápido** que si no perderemos el autobús". "Caminemos **rápidamente** que si no perderemos el autobús". "Ella fue **rápido** a la cocina". "Ella fue **rápidamente** a la cocina".

*En general un adjetivo funciona como adverbio y puede pasar a la categoría gramatical de adverbio cuando se inmovilizan en la forma masculina singular y funcionan como complementos circunstanciales que complementan a un verbo.*

***Rápido** es un adverbio adjetival y equivale a "**rápidamente**". **Los adverbios modifican al verbo y son invariables**: Mi inteligencia reacciona rápido/rápidamente. Lucia habla muy lento/lentamente. Rápido y lento modifican a reaccionar y hablar respectivamente.* **Por lo tanto "rápida" no podría actuar de adverbio, solo de adjetivo o sustantivo**. A no ser que desees decir "rápidamente", en cuyo caso si funciona como adverbio.

*Se llaman adjetivales por adoptar la forma de un adjetivo en singular (y en género masculino si el adjetivo es de dos terminaciones): **Corre** rápido; **Corren** rápido; Se **expresa** fatal; Se **expresan** fatal.*

Reciben el nombre de adverbios adjetivales o adverbios cortos.

En la actualidad los adverbios adjetivales se documentan tanto en el español europeo como en el americano, pero poseen más vitalidad en este último.

Referencia

http://hispanoteca.eu/gram%C3%A1ticas/Gram%C3%A1tica%20espa%C3%B1ola/Adverbios%20adjetivales%20o%20cortos.htm

> A diferencia de los complementos predicativos, que concuerdan con el
> sustantivo en género y número, los adjetivos adverbiales se forman
> inmovilizando ciertos adjetivos, que pierden así su flexión. Estos
> nuevos adverbios se pueden coordinar con otros similares, ya que no se
> consideran adjetivos.
>
> Hablar claro.
>
> Hablar bajo.
>
> Pasarlo estupendo.
>
> Levantarse temprano.
>
> Pasarlo fatal.
>
> Atar fuerte.
>
> Jugar sucio.
>
> Caminar lento.
>
> Correr rápido.
>
> Hacerlo rápido.
>
> Trabaja despacio y limpio.
>
> Bebe sabroso y despacio.
>
> No cambian de género ni de número:
>
> Los ataron fuerte.
>
> Juegan muy sucio.
>
> Corren rápido.
>
> Caminan lento.
>
> Lo hicieron muy rápido.
>
> Estos adverbios adjetivales pueden alternar con fórmulas adverbiales.
> No todos admiten la sustitución por el respectivo adverbio terminado
> en –mente:
>
> Habla claro.
>
> Habla muy claramente.
>
> Habla con mucha claridad.
>
> Juega sucio.
>
> Juegan suciamente.
>
> Juegan con suciedad.
>
> Camina lento.
>
> Caminan lentamente.
>
> Caminan con lentitud.
>
> Lo hizo rápido.
>
> Lo hizo rápidamente.
>
> Lo hizo con rapidez.
>
> Volar alto.
>
> *Volar altamente.
>
> Comprar caro.
>
> *Comprar caramente.
>
> Cantar bonito.
>
> *Cantar bonitamente.
>
> Los adverbios adjetivales se diferencian de los adverbios terminados
> en –mente en que no modifican a los adjetivos ni a los participios:
>
> Estaba hondamente afectado.
>
> *Estaba hondo afectado.
>
> Es infinitamente mejor.
>
> *Es infinito mejor.
>
> En otros casos no es posible la alternativa:
>
> Lo pagaron muy caro.
>
> Lo pasamos bárbaro.
>
> Aquello me asentó fatal.
>
> Los complementos predicativos admiten variación de género y número,
> concertando con un sustantivo (en función de sujeto o de complemento),
> mientras que los adjetivos adverbiales tienen como requisito que se
> inmovilicen en la forma masculina. Aunque este recurso no se puede
> extender indiscriminadamente:
>
> *Ganaron fácil.
>
> Ganaron con facilidad.
>
> Ganaron fácilmente.
>
> *Canta sencillo.
>
> Canta con sencillez.
>
> Los adjetivos adverbiales suelen modificar verbos como
>
> verbos de habla y de voz:
>
> decir, hablar, charlar, cantar
>
> verbos de entendimiento y sentimiento:
>
> ver, comprender, pasar, sentir, sentar, notar, percibir
>
> verbos que denotan energía:
>
> andar, pisar, golpear, dar
>
> verbos que expresan cantidad o intensidad:
>
> respirar, suspirar, costar, valer, sonar
>
> verbos de movimiento:
>
> correr, mover, ir, viajar
>
> Las restricciones sintácticas de los adverbios adjetivales son
> notables. Muchos de ellos forman con el verbo un predicado complejo
> que equivale casi a una locución verbal:
>
> pisar firme
>
> irle a uno bonito
>
> trabajar duro
>
> hablar claro
>
> jugar limpio
>
> jugar sucio
>
> chutar fuerte
>
> disparar raso
>
> sacar alto (fútbol)
>
> dominar fácil
>
> hilar fino (‘distinguir con gran sutileza’)
>
> caer bajo (‘degradarse, desprestigiarse’)
>
> Son numerosas las restricciones léxicas a las que están sometidos
> estos adverbios adjetivales:
>
> Comer sano.
>
> Comer saludable.
>
> Sin embargo, el adverbio sano no se admite con igual naturalidad con
> verbos como alimentarse, beber, nutrirse, tomar, aunque se trata de
> acciones que se pueden hacer de manera sana. Análogamente, limpio
> modifica al verbo jugar, pero no a otros con los que sí puede
> combinarse limpiamente: actuar, atravesar, competir, cortar, ganar,
> luchar, robar.
>
> Forman un grupo amplio los adjetivos adverbiales que expresan
> evaluación, generalmente positiva, de la manera de actuar, como los
> adjetivos bárbaro, bonito, chévere, fenomenal, genial, lindo,
> macanudo, rico, sabroso, brutal, bestial. Se asimilan a este grupo los
> sustantivos fenómeno y padre. Así como fetén, que suele considerarse
> como adjetivo, a pesar de que no posee flexión de género ni de número.
> Es de uso general el adverbio adjetival fácil.
>
> Jugó bárbaro.
>
> Me fue chévere.
>
> El vestido te sienta fenomenal.
>
> Lo pasamos genial.
>
> En este local se come macanudo.
>
> Nunca había visto a mis padres conversando tan sabroso.
>
> El espectáculo funciona fetén.
>
> Eso se dice fácil.
>
> Los adverbios adjetivales en sentido negativo son algo menos
> frecuentes, pero también posibles (saber feo, oler feo, sentir feo,
> doler feo), aunque no en todos los países de habla hispana:
>
> Esto huele feo.
>
> Esto sabe horrible.
>
> La comida me sentó fatal.
>
> Se llevan pésimo.
>
> Se suele emplear honro en sentido físico (cavar hondo, sembrar hondo,
> respirar hondo), en el figurado (calar hondo, llegar hondo) o en ambos
> simultáneamente. En cambio, profundo está mucho más restringido, ya
> que se usa con aspirar, respirar y pocos verbos más. El adverbio
> infinito se construye con sentir, alegrarse, lamentar y pocos verbos
> más en México, Centroamérica y España, pero no es general en todo el
> mundo hispanohablante (me alegro infinito de verte). El adverbio claro
> se usa con ver, hablar, distinguir y algunos más. Recio se emplea
> sobre todo con hablar, llover y pisar (Cuando salimos llovía recio;
> Los españoles pisan recio). Recto y derecho se adjuntan a verbos de
> movimiento (siga recto; continúe todo derecho). Las preferencias
> combinatorias de duro apuntan a trabajar, dar o pegar.
>
> Los adjetivos bueno, claro, evidente, natural, seguro se utilizan en
> respuestas y exclamaciones en las que pueden alternar también con
> adverbios o locuciones adverbiales. Evidente alterna con
> evidentemente; natural con naturalmente; obvio con obviamente. Otras
> veces alternan con expresiones relacionadas solo semánticamente entre
> sí (claro alterna con por supuesto o con evidentemente).
>
> Algunos adverbios adjetivales admiten diminutivos:
>
> hablar cortito
>
> volar bajito
>
> volver rapidito
>
> Algunos participios se asimilan a los adverbios adjetivales:
>
> Iba muy seguido por allí (‘muy frecuentemente’).

**NOTA**

**Coordinación de adverbios en -mente**

*Cuando se coordinan dos o más adverbios en -mente, lo normal es que dicha terminación aparezca tan solo en el último: **El Gobierno, mal que les pese a los opositores, es el que está en posición de capitalizar más rápida y eficientemente ese enojo colectivo.** ¿Y entonces es incorrecto repetir -mente? No, desde el punto de vista gramatical no hay nada que impida formar combinaciones como rápidamente, ágilmente y eficazmente. Sin embargo, esto resulta pesado, por lo que es preferible evitarlo.*

https://gramaticojac46.wordpress.com/2017/11/28/coordinacion-de-adverbios-en-mente/

Comment: ?Ella fue rápida a la cocina. Como el adjetivo se usa como adverbio, se debería mantener invariable: Ella fue rápido a la cocina

Comment: ¿En que estaría yo pensando? Gracias.

Comment: @Gustavson, hola, en la cuestión de más abajo pregunta Giuseppe Marco dice que ha leído en Centro Virtual Cervantes https://cvc.cervantes.es/foros/leer_asunto1.asp?vCodigo=52588, que "Para coordinar dos adverbios terminados en -mente , al primero lo escribimos en la forma femenina del adjetivo y al segundo, como adverbio", yo pienso que al ser el adverbio debe de ser invariable en cualquier caso y que esto no debería cambiar. He intentado buscar alguna regla que respalde esta teoría pero no he encontrado nada. ¿A ti te suena algo de esto o sabes de alguna referencia?. Gracias.

Comment: Es correcto lo que dice Giuseppe. El primer adverbio se apocopa y por ende mantiene la raíz femenina.

Comment: Algunas fuentes: https://gramaticojac46.wordpress.com/2017/11/28/coordinacion-de-adverbios-en-mente/

Comment: https://fundeu.fiile.org.ar/page/consultas/id/115/title/adverbios-terminados-en---mente-

Comment: https://blog.lengua-e.com/2012/coordinacion-de-adverbios-en-mente/

Comment: @Gustavson, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 2):

A lo mejor te refieres al caso de dos adverbios seguidos.

Ejemplo:

```
He hecho algo rápidamente.

He hecho algo descuidadamente.

He hecho algo rápida y descuidadamente.
```

Referencia:  [Centro Virtual Cervantes](https://cvc.cervantes.es/foros/leer_asunto1.asp?vCodigo=52588)

> Para coordinar dos adverbios terminados en -mente , al primero lo
> escribimos en la forma femenina del adjetivo y al segundo, como
> adverbio

Comment: @Diego Según el [Centro Virtual Cervantes](https://cvc.cervantes.es/foros/leer_asunto1.asp?vCodigo=52588), "Para coordinar dos adverbios terminados en -mente , al primero lo escribimos en la forma femenina del adjetivo y al segundo, como adverbio"

Comment: Hola Giusepe, gracias por el comentario, lo que no aclara Marcela es su fuente. He intentado encontrar lo que apuntas y no he hallado nada que señale la regla que comentas y que aparece en el enlace. Hasta donde tengo entendido el adverbio es invariable y siendo el adverbio "rápido", en el sentido de "rápidamente", "rápida" cumpliría la función de adjetivo y no de adverbio. Me gustaría comentarlo con @Gustavson  a ver que opina, antes de dar una respuesta definitiva. No obstante seguiré buscando. Gracias de nuevo por tenerlo en mente y a ver si podemos aclarar la cuestión que indicas. Saludos.

Comment: Giuseppe hola de nuevo, la cuestión se la consulte a Gustavson y me ha respondido que tu llevabas razón y que era correcto lo que habías comentado, pues como dice él, "el primer adverbio se apocopa y por ende mantiene la raíz femenina". Te pido perdón y gracias a ti he aprendido algo más. Saludos.